# Jquery click function to fully excecute before being able to re-click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a panel that toggles when a button is clicked, depending on whether a class is located on the panel. If the user clicks the button multiple times halfway through the panel sliding open it causes a display issue because it attempts to execute several times when its only meant to execute once.

How can I make it so the panel will only fire on a single click and disregard multiple clicks while its executing - only being able to toggle again once the function has finished?

```
$('.options_search_tab').click(function () {

   if (!$("#collapsePanel").hasClass("in")) {
    $('#options_search_btn').toggle();

} });
```

Comment: Where is the panel and the pertinent html?

Comment: If you know how long it take for the panel toggling to be fully executed, you can use setTimeout to block in-between clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is jQuery's `stop()` method:

https://api.jquery.com/stop/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#go').on('click', function() {
 $('.panel').stop(true).slideToggle(1500);
    });
});
```

```css
.panel {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background: cyan;
 position: absolute;
}
#go {
    margin-top: 305px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='panel'></div>
<button id='go'>Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could bind `off` and then `on` like that.

```
  $(".options_search_tab").off("click").on("click",function (event) {
      if (!$("#collapsePanel").hasClass("in")) {
     $('#options_search_btn').toggle();

   } });
```

The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()

Answer (score 0):

it's a best practice not to unbind an event only to rebind it later. Use a boolean instead.

```
var active = true;
$(".options_search_tab").click(function(){
   if(active){
       return;
   }
   active = false;
   if (!$("#collapsePanel").hasClass("in")) {
      $('#options_search_btn').toggle();
      active = true; // activate it again
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**`!$('#options_search_btn').is(':animated')`**

---

i.e.

```
if (
  !$("#collapsePanel").hasClass("in") && 
  !$('#options_search_btn').is(':animated')
)
```

Instead of having to repeatedly bind, this will specifically check if the animation is running using jQuery's custom `:animated` selector.

---

---

Alternatively: `$('#options_search_btn').stop().toggle();` should stop the animation and reverse it, so multi-clicks would be gracefully handled.

In fact, as general practice I recommend always adding `.stop()` before an animation.

Comment: this is really cool, I didn't know that! I appreciate this answer, but Robert gets the upvote because his answer was more direct at fixing the issue. If I could upvote two answers I would :P but thanks!